# Firefox sporadically ignoring mouse events

Tags: javascript, firefox, onclick, mouseevent

I am coding a JavaScript-application and have the problem, that on firefox about 5-10% of mouse clicks on a custom button are ignored.

The prototype for setting the click handler ist

```
function Button(parent, styleClassName) {
    Element.call(this, parent, "div");
    this.setStyleClass(styleClassName);
}

Button.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);
Button.prototype.constructor = Button;

Button.prototype.setOnClick = function(handler) {

    this.domNode.handler = handler;

    // sporadically skipped
    this.domNode.onclick = function(event) {
        console.log("ocl: " + event.currentTarget.id);
        this.handler(event);
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }

    this.domNode.ontouchstart = function(event) {
        console.log("ots: " + event.currentTarget.id);
        this.handler(event);
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

An example for an affected html element (the event handler is assigned correctly to the outer div):

```
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; left: 291px; top: 4px; width: 34px; height: 34px;" id="LandscapeScreen0_pMain_dlg_Element0_btnCloseDialog">
  <svg style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; width: 32px; height: 32px; cursor: pointer;" id="LandscapeScreen0_pMain_dlg_Element0_btnCloseDialog_RefSVG0">
    <use href="#svg08"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Some additional information:

- These handlers, once set, are never modified or removed
- Not even a log message is written to the console
- Using addEventListener() does not solve the problem
- The problem only exists in Firefox (tested on v25.0)
- most important: even the window does not retrieve the events!

regarding the last point: i added these lines for debugging:

```
window.onclick=function(e){console.log("onclick0");};
window.addEventListener("click",function(e){console.log("onclick1");}, true);
window.addEventListener("click",function(e){console.log("onclick2");}, false);
```

Whenever the button does not retrieve the mouse event, the window does not even receive one of these events either. So somehow, the events must have been dropped globally!?

So what I need is a hint what could be a possible cause for such a behaviour... it really seems to be non-deterministic when an event is skipped and when not.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does it make any difference where *exactly* you click on your element? For example, does it only work if you click on some visible text? Or conversely, only if you don't click on it?

Comment: Any floating elements that take up more space than they actually show? If they capture the event and preventDefault on it then that would make the event disappear but I guess it would do the same in all browsers. And I just see you set useCapture to true in one listener so at least that one should be invoked.

Comment: - it does not make a difference if i click on a text or in a free space

Comment: - there´s a hidden layer which fills the screen, but that does not swallow the events... as you mentioned, I tried with useCapture and without it.

Comment: just double-checked that there is no invisible layer which would take away the events. Also as mentioned, not even the window does receive the mouseclicks.